# PL/SQL global temp table no return records

Tags: oracle, plsql

In the Oracle PL/SQL, I have this code to learn global temp table. I define the temp table as this

```
CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE "TEST"."WORKTABLE"
         ( "VAL" VARCHAR2(2000 BYTE) ) 
      ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS ;
```

When I select it, it didn't show any record.

Please help.

```
declare
    r_countries countries%rowtype;
    v_country_id countries.country_id%type;
begin
     ----------- clean temp table ---------
    execute immediate 'truncate table worktable';

    select * into r_countries from countries r where r.country_id = 'AU';

    select country_id into v_country_id from countries where country_id = 'AU';

    insert into worktable
    select country_id from countries where country_id = 'AU';

    --dbms_output.put_line(r_countries.country_id);

    --dump_table('worktable');

     execute immediate 'select * from worktable'; -- no return

    ----------- clean temp table ---------
    execute immediate 'truncate table worktable';    
end;
/
```

Comment: How do you know that it returns no rows ? try `execute immediate 'select count(*) from worktable' into n;` (n should be a number variable) and then print `n`

Comment: Also (no time for proper answer), there's no need to truncate it. change to GTT to `on commit delete rows`. There's also no need to wrap the select in `execute immediate`.

Comment: because no any result in Dbms Output or Script Output.

Comment: If I didn't wrap the select in execute immediate, it complains PLS-00428: an INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement

Comment: According to the script you gave us, none should be printed. Try it like this: declare a variable `r worktable%ROWTYPE` and then `select * INTO r FROM worktable;` afterwards you can print whatever you got

Comment: That's because as @A.B.Cade said _you need_ an `into` clause, whether it's in execute immediate or not if you want to do anything with the data.

Comment: didn't get it. I have 'insert into worktable ..' , it should give me 1 record.

Comment: @user595234, I've put it in an answer

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the problem is in the Temporary table but in the script.
Try it like this:

```
declare
    r_countries countries%rowtype;
    v_country_id countries.country_id%type;

    r_worktable worktable%ROWTYPE;
begin
     ----------- clean temp table ---------
    execute immediate 'truncate table worktable';

    select * into r_countries from countries r where r.country_id = 'AU';

    select country_id into v_country_id from countries where country_id = 'AU';

    insert into worktable
    select country_id from countries where country_id = 'AU';

    --dbms_output.put_line(r_countries.country_id);

    --dump_table('worktable');

     select * INTO r_worktable from worktable; 

     dbms_output.put_line(r_worktable.VAL);

    ----------- clean temp table ---------
    execute immediate 'truncate table worktable';    
end;
/
```

Read more about `SELECT INTO` [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/selectinto_statement.htm#LNPLS01345)

Comment: my bad, I make thing complex. If I run this command, insert into worktable select country_id from countries ;  select * from worktable . it works. Then I put it into store proc, no return. the key point is insert into and temp table.